# Debug Error in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I am new to eclipse CDT software. I want to run an ADC program for LPC11C24 microcontroller.
My program is compiling without any errors but its not Debugging.

It displays an following error:-

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
source gdbinit
Error message from debugger back end:
gdbinit: No such file or directory.
gdbinit: No such file or directory.
```

And while compiling, I am able to read the ADC values but still it is not debugging.

Please help me out guys

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an initialization file for gdb (such as gdbinit) or edit the gdb launcher configuration so that it doesn't expect to find gdbinit.

Comment: thx for your reply.I did the latter one but still it displays the sam error.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to initalize file for gdb

Comment: The gdbinit file is just a text file of gdb commands. Here are a couple of lines that might help get you started: "set logging file mylogfile" and "set logging on". Put each of those on a separate line and see what you get in the log file. Of course, you can change "mylogfile" to whatever you like.